# Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'attr'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm examining a DOM element using console.log. The DOM element is an anchor:

```
 <a href="#" class="videoimage" data-id="ks3H_s3e-Wc"></a>
```

When I try to access its id and output it using either of the following lines:

```
console.log($this.attr(data-id));
```

or

```
console.log($this.data('id'));
```

I get an error:

> Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'attr'

('data' in the second case)

Does an anchor element not have the attr or data methods, or is my mistake something else?

Comment: Thanks but that's what i meant, it was a typo, that wasnt it

Comment: That error message happens because you are trying to use a jquery method 'attr' on an html object. So the answer to why you get the message is that 'this' is not a jquery object.

Answer (score 12):

That looks like its because your `this` reference is not a `jquery` object.
Try these instead:

```
$(this).data('id')
$(this).attr('data-id')
```

Comment: Thanks but that's what i meant, it was a typo, that wasnt it

Comment: I just did the exact same thing - was quite confused. Massive 'Doh!' moment. So it may not have fixed it for the OP, but it did for me :)

Answer (score 2):

It is telling you exactly what the problem is. `.data` and `.attr` are jQuery functions. If your want to get an attribute value using a javascript object do the following, after giving an id to your element:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("a").getAttribute("data-id"));
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/pFdEj/

Answer (score 0):

Something else is wrong in your page, then. The following **does** work:

```
$(this).data("id")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RQw8E/

How are you using `$(this)`?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

#### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="videoimage" data-id="ks3H_s3e-Wc">Click</a>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(".videoimage").click(function() {
    var dataID = $(this).data("id");
    var dataIDAttr = $(this).attr("data-id");
    console.log(dataID);
    console.log(dataIDAttr);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7K7xm/)

Are you sure you attached some sort of event to the function that calls these statements?

You could also use vanilla JS

```
var anchorArr = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchorArr.length; i++) {
    if(anchorArr[i].getAttribute("class")==="videoimage") {
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        //quick and dirty, there are better ways to do this
        console.log(anchorArr[i].getAttribute("data-id"));
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QuEmq/2/)